# Regex to match between custom text

Tags: c#, regex

This is giving me a hard time. I have an expression like this:
`isnull(Num([abc]), [a], [b]) + sum([d])`

I am trying to get everything that is enclosed within square brackets which is inside the `isnull()`. So from the above example, I should get `[abc], [a] and [b]` but not `[d]`.

I have come up with this - `isnull\((?:\[)(.*?)(?:\])` which gives me only `[abc]` but not `[a]` and `[b]`.

What can I change in my regex pattern so that I get the correct matches? I am using VS2019 and C# if it matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```cs
(?i)\bisnull\((?>[^][()]|(?<x>\[[^][]*])|(?<o>)\(|(?<-o>)\))*(?(o)(?!))\)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cbisnull%5C%28%28%3F%3E%5B%5E%5D%5B%28%29%5D%7C%28%3F%3Cx%3E%5C%5B%5B%5E%5D%5B%5D*%5D%29%7C%28%3F%3Co%3E%29%5C%28%7C%28%3F%3C-o%3E%29%5C%29%29*%28%3F%28o%29%28%3F!%29%29%5C%29&i=IsNull%28Num%28%5Babc%5D%29%2C%20%5Ba%5D%2C%20%5Bb%5D%29%20%2B%20sum%28%5Bd%5D%29&o=i). *Details*:

- `(?i)` - case insensitive matching enabled
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `isnull\(` - `isnull(` text
- `(?>[^][()]|(?<x>\[[^][]*])|(?<o>)\(|(?<-o>)\))*` - either any char other than `]`, `[`, `(` and `]`, or a `[...]` substring captured into Group "x", or a `(` and an empty value is pushed onto Group "o" capture stack, or a `)` and an empty value is popped from Group "o" capture stack, repeat zero or more times
- `(?(o)(?!))` - if Group "o" capture stack is not empty, fail the current match
- `\)` - `)` char.

See a [C# demo](https://ideone.com/5KODJG):

```cs
var pattern = @"\bisnull\((?>[^][()]|(?<x>\[[^][]*])|(?<o>)\(|(?<-o>)\))*(?(o)(?!))\)";
var text = "isnull(Num([abc]), [a], [b]) + sum([d])";
var result = Regex.Matches(text, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
                  .Cast<Match>().Select(p => p.Groups["x"].Captures)
                  .ToList();
foreach (var coll in result)
    foreach (var v in coll)
        Console.WriteLine(v);
// => [abc], [a], [b]
```

Or, if you are after a single match:

```cs
var result = Regex.Match(text, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)?.Groups["x"].Captures;
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", result)); // => [abc], [a], [b]
```

See [this C# demo](https://ideone.com/nZ4UCh).